# get multiple pictures ID from page's post (Facebook GraphAPI - Android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the posts from a page including all the pics related to the post.
I am able to get one picture from the post using object_id, but I need the other photos as well.

object_id returns only one Id which is the first photo's ID.

Please help.

```
GraphRequest greq =
                    new GraphRequest(
                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            "/{page-id}/posts",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse    response) {
                                    JSONArray data = null;

                                }
                            }
                    );
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putBoolean("redirect",false);
            params.putString("fields", "object_id");
            greq.setParameters(params);
            greq.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data should be in the [`attachments`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/attachment) field. In the `subattachments` sub-field specifically.

You should test this in the Graph API Explorer to see the API response and update your Android implementation based on that.